# Renaming files to longer names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I want to rename files named `ab-file.ext` to `cdef-file.ext` with Windows command prompt and I don't know how. I tried using `ren ab-*.ext cdef-*.ext` with `?` inserted in front and after the asterisks in every combination, but every time the name is changed to `cdef-le.exe`.

Can I somehow replace a part of a filename with a sequence of characters longer than the original part?

Comment: Take a look at: https://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files/776855#776855

Comment: @Paxz I did see that, but it seems overly complicated. If it can be done just by the ren command directly from console, I'd prefer to use this option.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the exact command you are using.

Comment: It cannot be done by the rename command directly.